# How to plot a heatmap with 3 continuous variables in r ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

Sample dataset is as below:
`count` is discrete variable, `temperature` and `relative_humidity_percent` are continuous variables.

The code to generate sample dataset:

```
templ = data.frame(count = c(200,225,610,233,250,210,290,255,279,250),
                  temperature = c(12.2,11.6,12,8.5,4,8.2,9.2,10.6,10.8,10.9),
                  relative_humidity_percent = c(74,78,72,65,77,84,83,74,73,75))
```

| count | temperature | relative_humidity_percent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | 12.2 | 74 |
| 225 | 11.6 | 78 |
| 610 | 12 | 72 |
| 233 | 8.5 | 65 |
| 250 | 4 | 77 |
| 210 | 8.2 | 84 |
| 290 | 9.2 | 83 |
| 255 | 10.6 | 74 |
| 279 | 10.8 | 73 |
| 250 | 10.9 | 75 |

I tried to plot a heatmap with ggplot2::stat_contour,

```
plot2 <- ggplot(templ, aes(x = temperature, y = relative_humidity_percent, z = count)) +
  stat_contour(geom = 'contour') +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = n)) +
  stat_contour(bins = 15) +
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(title = 'count'))

plot2
```

The result is:
[image]

Also, I tried to use ggplot::stat_density_2d,

```
> ggplot(templ, aes(temperature, relative_humidity_percent, z = count)) +
+   stat_density_2d(aes(fill = count)) 
Warning messages:
1: In stat_density_2d(aes(fill = count)) :
  Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill
2: The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: fill, z
ℹ This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the correct grouping structure in the data.
ℹ Did you forget to specify a `group` aesthetic or to convert a numerical variable into a factor? 
> geom_density_2d() + 
+   geom_contour() +
+   metR::geom_contour_fill(na.fill=TRUE) +
+   theme_classic()
Error in `+.gg`:
! Cannot add <ggproto> objects together
ℹ Did you forget to add this object to a <ggplot> object?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The result:
which was not filled with colour.
[image]

What I want is:

[image]

I want to replace `level` with `count` in the graph. However, since `count` variable is not factor. Therefore I cannot plot heatmap by using ggplot::geom_contour...

Comment: You could create a factor out of `count` with the `cut` function

Comment: I also think of this, but I am afraid that it will lead to loss of information

Comment: sorry, I think I misunderstood `geom_density_2d_filled`, I think it only shows the density as the filled value and I'm not sure if there is a way to manually specify another variable

Comment: I found a function from plot_ly package, not sure how it treats missing data (by imputation? interpolation? ) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand from your comment that you want to "fill the entire graph", thus having a less truthful representation of your three dimensional data, which would be more accurately represented as a scatter plot and local coding of your third variable. I understand that you intend to interpolate the observation density between the measured locations.

You can of course use geom_density_2d for this. Just do the same trick as in my other answer and uncount your data first.

NB this is of course creating bins of densities. Otherwise this type of visualisation with iso density lines is not working.

```r
ggplot(tidyr::uncount(templ, count)) +
  geom_density_2d_filled(aes(temperature, relative_humidity_percent))
```

[image]

Comment: When I used my data to run the code, the following error appeared:```Error in `geom_density_2d_filled()`:
! Problem while computing stat.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `seq_len()`:
! argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning messages:
1: Computation failed in `stat_density2d_filled()`
Caused by error:
! cannot allocate vector of size 2.7 Gb```

Comment: ```2: In min(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
4: In max(f) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf```

Comment: Did it mean that I cannot get the plot because of not enough RAM and both the x- and the y-data did not have a non-zero gap between their 1st and 2nd quantiles?

Comment: @doraemon I don't know - it might be that you have characters or NA in the sample which cannot be accounted for. Sometimes stat_density cannot compute with the default bandwidth if the sample size is too small. You can then change the bandwidth and see if this helps. Regarding the RAM - that seems a possibility.

Comment: Thank you! I think the error messages provided by ggplots 2 sometimes were difficult to understand...

Answer (score 1):

Just use geom_point and color according to your count. You can of course make your points square.

Or, if your count is not yet actually an aggregate measure and you want to show the density of neighbouring observations, you could use `ggpointdensity::geom_pointdensity` for this. (in your example, I have to uncount first).

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

templ = data.frame(count = c(200,225,610,233,250,210,290,255,279,250),
                   temperature = c(12.2,11.6,12,8.5,4,8.2,9.2,10.6,10.8,10.9),
                   relative_humidity_percent = c(74,78,72,65,77,84,83,74,73,75))

ggplot(templ) +
  geom_point(aes(temperature, relative_humidity_percent, color = count), shape = 15, size = 5)
```

[image]

```r
## first uncount 
templ %>%
  uncount(count) %>%
ggplot() +
  ggpointdensity::geom_pointdensity(aes(temperature, relative_humidity_percent))
```

[image]

Comment: I hope to fill the whole graph